# How to compile ffmpeg with the new Flascc compiler?

Tags: ffmpeg, alchemy, flascc

I have tried to compile ffmpeg with the new flascc compiler with the following parameters ( I set only h263 ability as a test):

```
PATH=/cygdrive/c/download/flascc/sdk/usr/bin:$PATH ./configure --enable-static 
--disable-shared --extra-libs=-static --extra-cflags=--static --disable-doc  --disable-ffplay 
--disable-ffprobe --disable-ffserver --disable-avdevice   --disable-avfilter   
--disable-pthreads  --disable-everything --enable-muxer=flv 
--enable-encoder=flv --enable-encoder=h263 --disable-mmx --disable-shared   
--prefix=bin/  --disable-protocols --disable-network --disable-optimizations --disable-debug 
--disable-asm --disable-stripping 
--prefix=/cygdrive/c/download/flascc/sdk/usr
```

Then I tried to make as follows:

```
PATH=/cygdrive/c/download/flascc/sdk/usr/bin:$PATH make

PATH=/cygdrive/c/download/flascc/sdk/usr/bin:$PATH make install
```

*.a files have been created in the subdirectories, like: libavcodec.a. But how can I create an .swf/.swc from the *.a files?

Thanks!
Charles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [docs](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/flascc/docs/Reference.html) it says you can produce SWFs with -emit-swf

> To generate a SWF, the executable format suitable for use in the Flash
>   Runtime, you pass the -emit-swf argument to GCC:
>
> `gcc -emit-swf hello.c -o hello.swf`

and SWCs with -emit-swc

> -emit-swc=    Emits a SWC that can be linked into a Flash Builder project or distributed for others to link into their own projects. You must
>   specify the namespace that you want to use to replace the default
>   com.adobe.flascc namespace, this lets you link multiple
>   FlasCC-generated SWCs into a single project.

Note that you'll need to write some kind of shim layer api for your AS3 code, or you can automate it with SWIG.